# How to prevent pendingintent from recreating an activity if launchmode set to 'singleTop'?

Tags: android, apk, android-pendingintent, android-package-managers

I have some trouble using Packagemanager to install an update of my application. My application is designed for internal use at my firm, so we can not use Google Play to handle those updates. So after launching the application, it quickly checks the version and downloads the update (if any).

Here is what I tried in my activity ( the file is the downloaded and newer version of the same application)

```
    public void installNewApkVersion(File file){
        PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
        try{
            PackageInstaller packageInstaller = getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
            int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
            session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

            addApkToInstallSession(session, file);
            // Create an install status receiver.
            Context context = LoginActivity.this;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
            // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
            session.commit(statusReceiver);
        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't install package", e);
        } catch (RuntimeException e){
            if(session != null){
                session.abandon();
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

For this to work, I had to override onNewIntent like so:

```
  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        boolean isloggedin = pref.getBoolean("Loggedin", false);



        if (ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int status = extras.getInt(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS);
            String message = extras.getString(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE);

            switch (status) {
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION:
                    // This test app isn't privileged, so the user has to confirm the install.
                    Intent confirmIntent = (Intent) extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
                    startActivity(confirmIntent);
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                    Log.w(TAG, "Install finished successfully");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed - status failure.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install failure aborted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed. Aborted.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_BLOCKED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install: failure blocked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed. Blocked.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install: failure conflicted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed. Found conflicts.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INCOMPATIBLE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install: incompatible!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed. Incompatible.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INVALID:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install: invalid!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Installation failed. Invalid.");
                    break;
                case PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_STORAGE:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Install failed: storage error! " + status + ", " + message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Install failed. Storage error.");
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unrecognized status received from installer: " + status,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Dont know what happened");
            }
        }
    }
```

This Activity runs in singleTop mode in order to receive the result of the installation. It runs fine unless the user cancels it when prompted.

Because if they so, the activity is recreated again instead of passing the result back to the original in @onNewIntent resulting two instance of the same activity in the backstack.

I suspected this issue happens on android 7, when tested android 10, instead of recreating the activity the task routed to @onNewIntent (STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED) as it should be.

How can I catch, if user aborts the installation?

The real purpose of this is to prevent the users from using my application if they have older version.

Or is there a way to somehow prevent this duplicate activities?

Comment: Does the `Intent` passed to `onCreate()` on Android 7 contain the `PackageInstaller` status information?

Comment: Sorry, but I am really new to the android world, and I do not know how I ask that information. Do you mean by getting the Intent extras through Bundle in onCreate?

Comment: @DavidWasser If that is what you are asking then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, if you check the extras in `onCreate()` on Android 7, do you see an extra with the package installer status? If so, then you can use that to determine if the update was successful or not.

Comment: Thanks, at least, I can now determine the status. Although, this is only half part of the solution, because another instance of the same activity is created anyway (but only if cancel selected at the prompt dialog). I somehow need the result in the original activity which started the whole process.

Comment: In `onCreate()` when you detect this situation try the following: `Intent x = getIntent(); x.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);startActivity(x);finish();`

Comment: Let me know if that works please.

Comment: YES! It works! That is what I am looking for., thank you!

Comment: Brilliant. I will create an answer and you can accept the answer. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the new instance of the `Activity` is created on Android 7, if the `Intent` contains the package installer status, you can do this in `onCreate()`:

```
Intent x = getIntent(); // This contains the package installer status
x.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
startActivity(x);
finish();
```

This will finish the new instance of the `Activity` and resume the previous instance of the `Activity` and pass the `Intent` in to `onNewIntent()` of the previous `Activity`.

NOTE: The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP` tells Android that it should ignore the current topmost `Activity` when deciding what to do with the `startActivity()` call. When you set this flag you are telling Android: "This `Activity` is going to finish, so don't consider it when deciding if you need to create a new instance or use an existing instance"

It is a hack, but should work :-)